# How to convert Binary Srtring into an integer array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary

I am reading a file as byte and converting them into binary string using

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(resultByteArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0')
```

After that, using `StringBuilder` I have combined all strings into one string. Now I want to convert this string into an array like [1,0,1,0....].

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Yes there is. Now go ahead and give it a try. If you get stuck, you can show us the code, explain where the problem is, and we'll be able to help.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but why go through `String` as an intermediate representation? Why not convert bytes directly to "bit-array" using bit manipulation?

Comment: @Andreas likely because the OP is a beginner. If it's already in a String of 1's en zeroes, rather than a byte[], then the OP doesn't need to understand about bitshifts and bit masking - it's just a for-loop now.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt OP is already doing `& 0xFF`. That's bit manipulation.

Comment: @Andreas True. There's a bit of a mismatch between that first expression and the rest of the question. I would guess that the OP just copied the first part from somewhere, but who is to tell..

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have solved it using toCharArray() method. I have tried another method before, but, I was getting error related dereferenced. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already compiled it into one big String, you can immediately convert it to a char array. There's a method called .toCharArray() that you can use to return a char array.

Here's an example of this:
http://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-tochararray

Additionally, if you want to convert it to a different type of array, you could iterate through and add it to an array that has the same size as the char array.

Best of luck!